# NodeJS - Stream video that is being downloaded

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am writing a program that will stream a video file that is currently being downloaded onto the drive. The problem I am having seems to be getting the browser to actually play the video. the script listens for file changes, and then streams the rest, but the browser doesnt do anything besides display a blank Video page.

```
var fs          = require('fs'),
    http        = require('http'),
    filename    = '/home/qrpike/Videos/topgears.mp4';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.url);
    if( req.url == '/video.mp4'){

        res.writeHead(200,{
            'Content-Type'          : 'video/mp4',
            'Cache-Control'         : 'public',
            'Connection'            : 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Disposition'   : 'inline; filename=topgears.mp4;',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' : 'binary',
            'Transfer-Encoding'     : 'chunked'
        });

        fs.open(filename, 'r', function(err, fd) {

            if (err) throw new Error('Could not open file');
            var position = 0;

            fs.stat(filename, read);
            fs.watchFile(filename, read.bind(null, null));

            function read(err, stat) {

                var delta = stat.size - position;
                if (delta <= 0) return;

                fs.read(fd, new Buffer(delta), 0, delta, position, function(err, bytes, buffer) {

                    console.log("err", err, "bytes", bytes, "position",position,"delta",delta);
                    res.write(buffer.toString('binary'));

                });

                position = stat.size;

            } 

        });

    }

}).listen(1337);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 2):

So this answer depends on [growing-file](https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file), which in theory does what you want. My concern is that the project hasn't had a commit in two years so I have no idea if it still works. That being said, this worked for me locally (though I didn't test piping to the video file):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var GrowingFile = require('growing-file');

var FILENAME = '/home/dave/Desktop/video/video.ogg';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var file;
  if (req.url === '/video.ogg') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'video/ogg'
    });
    file = GrowingFile.open(FILENAME);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.end('Not Found');
  }
});

server.listen(1337);
```